# Why Sharepoint create Profile automatically?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, asp.net-membership, profile, claims-based-identity

im using sharepoint 2010 with claimsAuthentification (SQLMembership Provider)

when user is authentified the first time, sharepoint create automatically a profile for this

user, please how can i avoid this.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't with the out of the box SqlMembershipProvider, SharePoint needs to store user data somewhere, it just just hooks into the provider. You would need to write your own MembershipProvider to accomplish this.

Comment: thx, the problem is that i have to create profiles programatically and set some propreties but with this behivor i have now duplicate profile 1 created using object model and the second created by sharepoint, for the same persone like :​i:0#.f|sqlmembershipprovider|anna.maria 
i:0#.f|sqlmembershipprovider|anna.maria

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you could configure a second profile provider with a different application name within the same web.config and use that one for the programmatic access.

Comment: @greg thx, i will use the default profile created by sharepoint and trying to update it

Comment: That is the way to go, and just use the sharepoint object model to create profiles!